# how to get debugging/verbose information while running package.json scripts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I have the following scripts in my package.json file

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "watchify -o js/bundle.js -v -d .",
    "build": "browserify . | uglifyjs -cm > js/bundle.min.js"
  },
```

when i run `npm build`,  the command executes and moves to  a fresh new  line in the terminal and the script has'nt been built.

To figure out the problem,
how can i get more verbose/debugging info from running this command?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following command?

`npm build --verbose`

Comment: I just get general info when on running that command http://pastebin.com/hyxM3JKW

Comment: What more are you expecting?

Comment: well it's like running an empty shell script, i can't seem to find the source of why the script is'nt being built